# org.w3c.dom.DOMException: NAMESPACE_ERR java webservice

Tags: java, soap, xerces, saaj

I was trying to build a webservice client which can accept any type of request document(with or without namespaces) invoke webservice. But I was facing the below mentioned. Can anyone please help me on this. I'm aware that was a solution to similar problem where they asked to set 'setNamespaceAware' to true for the document factory

```
factorydocFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
docFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
```

But in my case the request document comes from somewhere else and I have no control on it.  Once i receive the document i would need to do something which makes the namespaces to be ignored but Im not aware how to do this.

---

Code:

```
        public SOAPMessage createSoapRequest(Document requestDoc)
                    throws SOAPException, DOMException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {            
                System.setProperty("javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory", "com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.SOAPMessageFactory1_1Impl");
                MessageFactory mf = SOAPMessageFactory1_1Impl.newInstance();
                SOAPMessage request = mf.createMessage();
                SOAPPart soapPart = request.getSOAPPart();    
                SOAPEnvelope env = soapPart.getEnvelope();                  
                SOAPBody soapBody = env.getBody();
                /* adding the input to soapbody */
                soapBody.addDocument(requestDoc);    
                return request;
            }
```

Input passed:

```
        <tem:abc xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
            <tem:def>
                <MESSAGE>
                    <Component>
                        <Parameters>
                          <adsfds>123 </adsfds>
                        </Parameters>
                    </Component>
                </MESSAGE>
            </tem:def>
        </tem:abc>
```

Exception I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.w3c.dom.DOMException: NAMESPACE_ERR: An attempt is made to create or change an object in a way which is incorrect with regard to namespaces.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ElementNSImpl.setName(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ElementNSImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.impl.ElementImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.impl.ElementFactory.createElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.SOAPDocumentImpl.createElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.CoreDocumentImpl.importNode(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.CoreDocumentImpl.importNode(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.CoreDocumentImpl.importNode(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.SOAPDocumentImpl.importNode(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.impl.BodyImpl.addD`enter code heredocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.custom.util.TestWebServiceCaller.createSoapRequest(TestWebServiceCaller.java:224)
    at com.custom.util.TestWebServiceCaller.invokeWS(TestWebServiceCaller.java:103)
    at TestWS.main(TestWS.java:30)
```

Comment: To editors: yes, the question looks prettier now, and the XML certainly *looks* better now that you've made the start and end tags match. But does it still represent the OP's actual problem? (assuming it ever did)

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you... my question was how can I prevent this error when namespaces were present in the input document to the code. I want to pass the input document(with namespaces) to webservice 'as it is'

Comment: My comment was to @Barett and any other person that edited this post. Your original post had malformed XML, which looked as if you'd half-anonymized it. The editors helpfully fixed this malformed XML, but that wasn't really helpful in this case. To diagnose the problem, we need to see the *real* XML. There are only a few reasons that [setName()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/com/sun/org/apache/xerces/internal/dom/ElementNSImpl.java#ElementNSImpl.setName%28java.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.String%29) throws NAMESPACE_ERR, and none of them appear here

Comment: If I had to guess, you're getting the `Document` pre-constructed from some other code in your system, and that other code has created a "qualified" element name without a corresponding namespace (ie, constructed the document with `createElement()` rather than `createElementNS()`).

Comment: Actually, you probably won't see that by serializing the document. I think you'll have to write some code that goes through `requestDoc` recursively, for each element printing `getNamespaceURI()`, `getNodeName()`, `getPrefix()`, and `getLocalName()`. I'm betting you'll find an element where `getNodeName` returns something that looks like a qualified name, but the other three return `null`.

Comment: Yes you are correct, the document is created using createElement.

Comment: the real xml is `<tem:Lookup xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
    <tem:xmlIn>
        <MESSAGE>
            <Component>
                <Parameters>
                    <KEY>12134</KEY>                   
                </Parameters>
            </Component>
        </MESSAGE>
    </tem:xmlIn>
</tem:Lookup>`

Comment: I also tried `DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance() ;
  docFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
  Document req = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();
  req.appendChild(req.importNode(requestDoc.getDocumentElement(), true));
  soapBody.addDocument(req);
` but even this didnt work for me, it throwed the same error. I wonder why it didnt work even after setting setNameSpaceAware to true for the new document . Any thoughts?

Comment: If the document was created improperly (I assume they used setAttribute() to set the "namespace"), then your only solution will be to serialize it and then parse the serialized version. Unless you can get whoever built the document to use the correct methods to do so.

Comment: I just published a [blog post](http://blog.kdgregory.com/2014/07/namespaces-arent-just-attributes.html) inspired by this question. I don't know if it's your actual problem, but it might give you some help in debugging.